# embedded pdf viewer doesn't show me the page I just compiled but a random one

Tags: pdf, viewers, preview

I'm using Texmaker 4.4.1, and I have the following problem:
When I compile my document, the empedded pdf viewer doesn't show me the corresponding lines I just compiled, and it may show me even a different page (for example even two chapters later!!). I want it to show me in pdf, what I just compiled and not "throwing" me at a random page!
How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you press F6 and then F7? Also, are you using the synctex option? Check it on Options>Configure>Commands menu.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer!
I was using a multi-file latex (each chapter in a separate tex)  and I needed to define my template.tex (the template.tex contains all the \usepackage commands and all the \include)  as Master Document.  This was done by opening the template.tex file with texmaker and then options-> define current document as "Master Document".

Comment: Well, but how could you compile your non master files if they don't have the preamble? Some errors should appear. But yes, the right way is to define Master document and then you can compile the same file with any other opened.

Comment: I was compiling the template.tex file which contains the preamble. But the template.tex file has the \include  command which "calls" the separate chapters-tex files.